# How to configure the SSH timeout with the Ansible Mitogen plugin?

Tags: ansible

I have the following vanilla Ansible configuration that helps go through a slow Bastion:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args=-o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=60s -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath=/tmp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r
```

However, when using the Mitogen plugin with this configuration:

```
[defaults]
# https://mitogen.networkgenomics.com/ansible_detailed.html
strategy_plugins = mitogen-0.2.9/ansible_mitogen/plugins/strategy
strategy = mitogen_linear
```

The timeout in the `[ssh_connection]` section clearly isn't used.

The [Mitogen SSH documentation](https://mitogen.networkgenomics.com/ansible_detailed.html#ssh) alludes to some SSH configuration, but it's unclear where to set these variables.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ansible_ssh_timeout` variable. You can set it in `group_vars` or in the command line:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e "ansible_ssh_timeout=60"
```